# Is the correct phrase "free run" or "free roam?"

Tags: expressions

Is the correct phrase "free run" or "free roam," as in "the dog has free run of the house"?

Answer (score 5):

["Free run" seems to be the hands down winner](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=free+run%2C+free+roam&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), with "free roam" barely registering as a phrase.

[image: Google Ngram]

(["Free range"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=free+run%2Cfree+roam%2C+free+range&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is another strong contender.)

Answer (score 3):

The expression I know is "free run of" meaning the dog (in your case) can make full use of the house. But I've heard it without the adjective "free", too.

Answer (score 1):

"free roam" is the most common in my experience (southern UK), but usually without qualification (i.e. "the dog had free roam" rather than "the dog had free roam *of the house*)